# convert currentDateTime to String and the opposite using DateTimeFormatter class in FLEX 4

Tags: datetime, flex4, formatter

Hello i do the following:

```
var currentDate:Date = new Date();
```

in order to get the current date which i want to write it to file and afterwards get it back to a Date field, which is the best way? i want to have both the date and the time, is DateTimeFormatter suitable for this(especially as far as string-to-date is concerned)? and how can this be done?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used the static method [parseDateString() in the mx.formatters.DateFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/formatters/DateFormatter.html#parseDateString%28%29) class in projects where I needed to deserialize the human readable form of date strings.

However, in projects where the serialized value doesn't really need to be human readable, I've simply stored the value in the [time property of the Date object](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#time).  Then, to deserialize, created a `new Date()` and set it's `time` to that saved value.

The latter is definitely the more efficient.